# My web client logs out properly but mobile client does not

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I'm using express/express-session/passport on a Node backend and this is my logout code.

```
// GET /logout
exports.logout = (req, res) => {
  req.logout();

  if (req.body.type === "mobile") {
    return res.status(200).json({success: true});
  }

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

This web application runs on `http://myapp.dev:3000`. I can login/logout without any issues as long as I am on the web application and click the logout button.

I also have an Ionic (a mobile application) that runs on `192.168.2.30:8100`. When I click logout button in my mobile app, I make a request to /logout as usual.

```
$stateProvider.state("auth.signout", {
    url: "/signout",
    controller: "SignoutController",
    resolve: {
        redirect: function($http, $state, Config) {

            $http.get(`${Config.url("/logout")}`, {
                type: "mobile"
            }, {
                withCredentials: true
            }).then(res => {
                $state.go('auth.signin');
            }).catch(res => {
                console.log(res);
                alert("Could not log out");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When I click the logout button on my mobile client, I get the JSON back but I am unable to delete cookie from my mobile client so it keeps reconnecting.

Any idea how can I prevent this?

Comment: What have you tried to delete your cookie and what errors are you getting when you try to delete it?

Comment: @VtoCorleone What am I supposed to do? It should be backend's duty to tell webview to delete cookies and I believe `req.logout()` sets necessary headers for that. My web application has no code apart from me entering `myapp.dev/logout` and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how the server is doing Set-Cookie?

What's the problem with guaranteeing that your cookie is deleted on the client?

```
$http.get(`${Config.url("/logout")}`, {
  type: "mobile"
}, {
  withCredentials: true
}).then(res => {
  document.cookie = 'cookieName=;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;'
  $state.go('auth.signin');
}).catch(res => {
  console.log(res);
  alert("Could not log out");
});
```

Comment: It is basically express-session along with passport module. It looks like this: https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js

document.cookie is always `null` on Android/Cordova. I guess APK is caching the cookie somewhere else like application cache?